# Exception raised during rendering: invalid LOC header (bad signature) in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, graphical-layout-editor

**Exception raised during rendering: invalid LOC header (bad signature)**

Exception raised during rendering: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- ImageView (Change to android.widget.ImageView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Yesterday my system is force shut-downed unfortunately without saving the eclipse workspace. After that i got this **error while opening the graphical view of the android layout files.** But no error in xml files. They are perfect working files.

Any help would save my life. I'm struggling more than one day at a tight deadline.

Answer (score 0):

I got this king of error during a maven build in eclipse.
I deleted the contents of directory that eclipse builtin maven use to store downloaded files under

> $HOME/.m2/repository

ant executed the clean target and rebuild.

Maybe it holds some stuff for android too.